# JavaScript getElementsByCustomTag('value')?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I know getElementsByName('something') that returns the elements with name="something", but I want to return a list of elements where custom="something", how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems it was easier than I thought.

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');

for (elem = 0;elem < elements.length;elem++)
 {
  element = elements[elem];

  if (element.lang != 'php')
   break;
  ...
 }
```

The above happened to work in my situation. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard API in the DOM to do this.

If you do not mind adding [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to your project, you could query your elements using the jQuery attribute selector:

```
$("[custom='something']")
```

Comment: I rather not, because it adds one more HTTP download for the client just for this single feature... but thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: If you are concerned about the number of HTTP downloads, then you are already concatenating all your JS files into one, are you?. Adding another one for jQuery should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) lists all the functions of the Document object in the JavaScript available in browsers. Thus it provides `getElementById()`, `getElementByName()` and `getElementByTagName()`.

I guess need to use something like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to gain more freedom as it allows you to express more complex "[queries](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext)". I'm not sure, but that might also be slower, depending on how often you have to look up things.